# How to remove bullets and underline from auto complete

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I did autocomplete using jquery and web service. Auto complete is showing with bullets and underline.

How can I remove it?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery UI css?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by adding a css

```
list-style-type: none;
```

And for removing the underline use

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Or you can try this with **jquery**

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('list-style-type', 'none');
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some Jquery statements and get easily:

```
  $('#myInput').autocomplete({ source: function (event, ui) {
      ...
      .....
      ......
      $('.ui-autocomplete').css('list-style-type', 'none').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    });
```

Or Try to set CSS style :

```
    ul.ui-autocomplete
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```