# Can't remove bullets from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have trying to remove bullets from autocomplete list without success. Already try every results from search in this site:

It's the most obviously resource but don't work for me.

1 - [How to remove bullets from jquery autocomplete result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028642/how-to-remove-bullets-from-jquery-autocomplete-result)
2 - [Autocomplete is showing bullets beside the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247572/autocomplete-is-showing-bullets-beside-the-data)
3 - [How to remove bullets and underline from auto complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973282/how-to-remove-bullets-and-underline-from-auto-complete)

No one works.

Look for my problem here:

www.mksnet.com.br/18.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself. Questions on Stack Overflow are for future visitors. If you fix the problem, the question could become useless.

Comment: Newbie here. Will learn about that. So, the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert this code to your css

```css
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:before {content:'';}
```

It's remove before content from item.

Comment: @EdersonLuizGobbi You're welcome. I'm happy to help :)